# The set of matrices where from the second row down are all equal to 0

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $R=\mathrm{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be the ring of all $n \times n$ matrices with entries in the real number $\mathbb{R}.$ The set of matrices where from the second row down are all equal to $0$, is denoted by $\Gamma,$ is an additive subgroup of $R$ under multipication.

I want to find them all right $0$-divisors and left $0$-divisors in $\Gamma$. I was suggested that $A\in R$ is a $0$-divisor if and only if $\det A=0$ and $A\neq0.$ However, I only prove that if $A\in R,$ then $\det A=0$ and $A\neq0.$ I used to use Adjugate matrix to prove this converse via ${\displaystyle (\det A)I=A\operatorname {adj} A=(\operatorname {adj} A)\,A.}$ But I observe that $\mathrm{adj} A=0$ for $A\in R.$ Thus it is not available. After that, I don't know us this hint how to find all one side $0$-divisors. Thanks for all support!

Comment: Are you finding the zero divisors in $M_n(\mathbb R)$ or just the zero divisors in $\Gamma$? Are you trying to prove that $A$ is a zero divisor if and only if $\det(A)=0$ or are you taking it as given?

Comment: I tried to prove it but I don't finish this converse. If $A\in R$ is a $0$-divisor, then $AB=0$ for some $B\in R\setminus\{0\},$ and so $\det A=0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\det(A)=0$. Then for some $\mathbf{v}\neq 0$, $A\mathbf{v}=0.$ Then
$$
A\left[
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\mathbf{v}& \cdots& \mathbf{v} 
\end{array}
\right]=0
$$
with $\mathbf{v}$ repeated $n$ times.
Thus $A$ is a zero divisor.